# if I enter the wrong option I get this error (TypeError: 'str' object is not callable)

Tags: python, string, function

In the input when I enter a name instead of (y,n,m), its pops with this error (TypeError: 'str' object is not callable), I don't know what means and I try fixing it but it didn't work. Someone, please help. when entering a name like (john) in the input instead of the options I get that error.

```
def return_menu():
    console = Console()
    return_menu = console.input("[bold cyan on magenta]Would like to search for another player(y/n) or return to the "
                                "Menu?(m):[/]  ")
    
    return_menu = return_menu.lower()

    
    if return_menu == "y":
        players_stats()
    
    elif return_menu == "m":
        menu()
   
    elif return_menu == "n":
        print("Good bye and Thank you for using our system!")
        exit()
    else:
        console.print("======================================================================", style="bold red")
        console.print("           Please choose the most appropriate option", style='bold red')
        console.print("======================================================================", style="bold red")
        return_menu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your variable `return_menu` and `def return_menu()` have same name.
try this:

```
def return_menu():
    console = Console()
    r_m = console.input("[bold cyan on magenta]Would like to search for another player(y/n) or return to the "
                                "Menu?(m):[/]  ")
    
    r_m = r_m.lower()

    
    if r_m == "y":
        players_stats()
    
    elif r_m == "m":
        menu()
   
    elif r_m == "n":
        print("Good bye and Thank you for using our system!")
        exit()
    else:
        console.print("======================================================================", style="bold red")
        console.print("           Please choose the most appropriate option", style='bold red')
        console.print("======================================================================", style="bold red")
        return_menu()
```